# {{Form::select('size',array('admin' => 'Admin', 'user' => 'User'),['class' => 'form-control'])}}

Tags: laravel

This is syntax not working

```
{{Form::select('size',array('admin' => 'Admin', 'user' => 'User'),['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

Comment: Please tell us the error that you get.

Comment: in this bootsrap class not working

Comment: Then check your css. Alternatively, check the source code after the page is rendered. It may not be getting converted to the HTML you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the syntax won't work because you are missing the third parameter which is the default select option, so you either pass a value to be selected or you use `null`.

So try this:

```
{{Form::select('size', array('admin' => 'Admin', 'user' => 'User'), null, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```